# How to include image files in a Rust library

Tags: rust

I'm creating a Rust library that has structs that represent individual Hanafuda playing cards and a card deck as a whole. I'm planning on creating several different games with the same deck of cards, so I'd prefer it be in a library instead of hard-coded into each project. Each card has an associated PNG image of its face.

The problem I'm having is how to access those images once the library is included as a dependency in another project. I'd prefer to package the images as plain old image files because I'm not yet sure if I want to build a game with gtk-rs or rust-qt, or some other GUI library.

Here's the struct and new function for a playing card:

```
pub struct HanafudaCard {
    pub month: Month,
    pub plant: Plant,
    pub face: String,
    pub card_type: CardType,
    pub value: u8,
    pub image_path: String
}

impl HanafudaCard {
    pub fn new(month: Month, plant: Plant, face: String, card_type: CardType, value: u8, image_path: String) -> Self {
        HanafudaCard {
            month,
            plant,
            face,
            card_type,
            value,
            image_path
        }
    }
}
```

I used a `build.rs` script to copy the image directory into the target build:

```
extern crate fs_extra;
use std::env;
use fs_extra::dir::{copy, CopyOptions};

fn main() {
  println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");

  let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
  copy("./res/img", &out_dir, &CopyOptions::new()).unwrap();
}
```

`OUT_DIR` in this case points to `target/debug/build/hanafuda_deck_rs-0327e50b2deefc9f/out/img/01.png` when I run `cargo build` in the library directory.

Individual card images are assigned to `HanafudaCard` structs in `HanafudaDeck::new` like this:

```
impl HanafudaDeck {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        HanafudaDeck {
            cards: vec![
                HanafudaCard::new(Month::January, Plant::Pine, String::from("Crane and Sun"), CardType::Bright, 20, String::from(format!("{}/img/01.png", env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap()))),
                // other 47 card definitions here
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For now, I'm importing the crate via Git. When this library is imported into another project, image files ends up in ex. `./target/debug/build/hanafuda_deck_rs-edd17a51cf1d380c/out/img/01.png` upon running `cargo build`.

But when I run `cargo run`, I get the following panic:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/hanafuda-grid`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent', /home/shane/.cargo/git/checkouts/hanafuda-deck-rs-ccc798d3bc429f2a/3909aa2/src/lib.rs:87:175
```

Why did `OUT_DIR` end up pointing at that directory instead of the directory in `./target`? Should I be doing something different to get the paths to match up?